# Android: break or return true?

Tags: android, menu, switch-statement

For items in a menu, what is better to end the case with: "break;" or "return true;"?  Would the answer change with multiple menu items (multiple cases)?  Please explain.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_delete:
            taskAdapter.deleteCheckedItems();
            **break;**  or **return true;**
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: These both do the same thing. I'm not sure if there is a performance hit if you use break because it has to go to another line but if there was it would be negligible.

Comment: So return true might be slightly better from a performance standpoint because return true does not have to go to another line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.
According to this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: So does that mean the final (last) case should always have the break statement?

Comment: Yes, then your statement couldn't have fall through.

Answer (score 0):

**break** is used to exit from loop. **return** will exit the whole method - used to return to the step where it was called or to stop further execution (also can return a value to the caller). In case switch statements, use **break** if you want the switch to still look through the other cases. Use **return** to finish the method e.g. does not look through the other cases.

Comment: break or return will force code to exit switch statement, no difference in that. break will execute code after the whole switch statement but return wont't